# Quick Design approach needed

Tags: data-structures, hashmap

I am reading a huge file having orderTime (DateTime object) & orderID (String). Which data structure can I use and how - so that, given a time range I can give all the order id's as part of that time range?

Comment: File example
2017-07-01 01:01:09 Order1
2017-07-01 01:31:59 Order2
2017-07-01 02:29:59 Order3
Now for time range 1.30 - 2.30 - i should retreve Order2 & Order3

Answer (score 0):

You can use linear or non-linear data structures. Linear data structure could be as simple as a linked list having the order Id's in a time-line based sorted order. 
You can also go for Calender-Queue's. They are very efficient for querying between ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some sort of [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), allowing you to quickly find not only the corresponding value for some key, but also all the parts of the tree being larger or smaller than that key.

For example, in Java you could use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and particularly the `headMap`, `tailMap`, and [`subMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap-K-K-) methods. Example usage:

```
SortedMap<Date, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(someDate, someId);
...
SortedMap<Date, String> between = map.subMap(fromDate, toDate);
```